# Restore TensorFlow model with Dropout applied

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm having problems restoring TF models which I've trained using dropout. How do I set the `keep_prob` to `1.0`?

The code which I've tried below is not working, and I think it's due to the fact that I create a new `tf.placeholder` when I restore the model. But how do I restore the `keep_prob` placeholder?

Here's my restoring code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

logs_path = ...


def readImage(filenames):
    filenameQ = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames, shuffle=False)

    reader = tf.WholeFileReader() # Magic function
    key, value = reader.read(filenameQ)

    image = tf.image.decode_png(value)
    image.set_shape([101, 201, 1])
    return image

image = readImage([("../image-to-tfrecords/train/chef/chef%d.png" % i) for i in range(5000)])

merged_summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()

class CNN:
    """
    Class to load saved CNN
    """
    def __init__(self, model_file, imgsize=None, visualize=True, saver=None, batch_size=100):
        self.model_file = model_file
        self.saver = saver
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        if imgsize:
            self.img_h = imgsize[0]
            self.img_w = imgsize[1]

    def predict(self, X):
        # OUTCOMMENTED THIS LINE:
        #keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)  # dropout (keep probability)

        """
        Prediction Routine
        """
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
            sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())

            train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logs_path + '/train', sess.graph)

            graph = tf.get_default_graph()

            # restore the model
            self.saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(self.model_file) #, input_map={"keep_prob_training:0": keep_prob}, import_scope='imported'
            self.saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./tfmodels/cnn/'))

            x, y = tf.get_collection('inputs')

            # ADDED THE FOLLOWING LINE:
            keep_prob = tf.get_collection('dropout_train')[0]

            logits, predict_op = tf.get_collection('outputs')
            probs = tf.nn.softmax(logits)

            coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
            threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

            predictions = []

            train_writer.add_graph(sess.graph)

            for i in range(5000):
                batch_xs = sess.run(X)

                # Reshape batch_xs if only a single image is given
                #   (numpy is 4D: batch_size * heigth * width * channels)
                batch_xs = np.reshape(batch_xs, (-1, self.img_w * self.img_h))
                prediction = sess.run([predict_op], feed_dict={x: batch_xs, keep_prob: 1.0})

                predictions.append(prediction[0][0])

            train_writer.close()

            # finalize
            coord.request_stop()
            coord.join(threads)

        return predictions

    @staticmethod
    def load(model_file, imgsize=[201, 101]):
        """ Load TF metagraph """
        print "Loading Model from: " + model_file
        return FNN(model_file, imgsize)


def main():
    """ Main """
    # Load and predict
    model = CNN.load("tfmodels/cnn/tf.model.meta")
    model.predict(image)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Update**

Below is the graph from tensorboard. I've compared the graph from the save program and the restore program and the graphs are the same :)

[image: logits]

[image: fc1]

[image: dropout]

Comment: The updated code looks correct to me. My best guess for why it isn't working is that (for some reason) `predict_op` doesn't depend on `keep_prob`. That would depend on how the graph is built in the original program, but you might be able to check it by writing a quick BFS on the `tf.Tensor.op.inputs` property (or e.g. using the TensorBoard graph visualizer) to check.

Comment: I've just added the tensorboard visualizations for the graph :)

Comment: They seem to check out... although it's hard to say from the zoomed in version whether the `keep_prob` in the visualization is the same as your new `keep_prob_training:0` tensor. Is it possible that there's a name mismatch somewhere? (That would also explain the `input_map` error: it will look for a tensor with that exact name in the `GraphDef`.)

Comment: It doesn't look like it. For fun I've just tried to change the name of the `get_collection('some_other_name', keep_prob)` and then it fails. The log file is here if it is easier for you: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hca15peij2ks8c4/events.out.tfevents.1490129107.sdur-2?dl=0

Comment: Looking at the graph in that file, there are two potential placeholders. One is called `keep_prob:0` and the other is called `Logits/Fc1/dropout/keep_prob:0`. Perhaps it's the latter one that you need to feed?

Comment: Ah, I did not notice that! Replacing the get collection with: `keep_prob = graph.get_tensor_by_name('Logits/Fc1/dropout/keep_prob:0')` solves it! Now it returns class 0 for all predictions when `keep_prob: 0.0` and it is fully deterministic when `keep_prob:1.0`. But why is there "suddenly" two placeholders? I've only defined one, now as: `keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='keep_prob')` in the save program

Comment: Oh god! I found a terrible mistake! In my train program i had `fc1 = tf.nn.dropout(fc1, dropout)` which were supposed to be: `fc1 = tf.nn.dropout(fc1, keep_prob)`, where dropout is simply the raw value of `0.5`. Now it works with the `get_collection()` method as well. I'm so sorry!

Comment: Don't worry about it :). I'm glad we got to the bottom of it!

Comment: BTW It also works with the `input_map` :) as long as  `import_scope='imported'` is set. Thank you for all your time. It means the world!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've correctly observed the problem. The `keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)` tensor is unconnected to the graph that you import with [`tf.train.import_meta_graph()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/import_graph_def), so feeding that tensor has no effect on the inference.

The solution will depend on how you built your initial model. You will first need to identify the `name` of the tensor that is used as `keep_prob` in your original graph. For example, if you created it at the top level of your original graph with the following statement:

```
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name="keep_prob_training")
```

...the name would be `"keep_prob_training:0"`. However, if you did not pass an explicit `name` argument then the name will be something like `"Placeholder:0"`, `"Placeholder_1:0"`, etc. The most reliable way to tell would be to `print(keep_prob.name)` in the original program.

Once you have this name (which I'll assume is `"keep_prob_training:0"` for the sake of concreteness), you need to make a simple modification to the `tf.train.import_meta_graph()` call, in order to set an `input_map` and connect your new `keep_prob` tensor to the imported graph. The following should work:

```
self.saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(
    self.model_file, input_map={"keep_prob_training:0": keep_prob})
```

After you do this, feeding the `keep_prob` tensor will allow you to control the dropout applied at inference time.

Comment: First of all thank you for your great reply. I tried this and got: `ValueError: tf.import_graph_def() requires a non-empty `name` if `input_map` is used.` How do I fix this? I have set the name of the placeholder as to your answer :)

Comment: btw should I add the `x` and `y` placeholders in the same manner as `keep_prob` ? As you can see in my code above I am restoring them from a collection. However I tried saving the `keep_prob` to a collection and restoring that without luck. It is still not connected. But it seems to work for `x` and `y`

Comment: I think the `ValueError` has been fixed in a more recent version, so you could either (i) switch to a nightly build, or (ii) pass a scope name (e.g. `import_scope="imported"`) when calling `tf.train.import_meta_graph()`).

Comment: If the collection method works for `x` and `y`, you should probably keep using that, but the `input_map` should work as well. I'm not sure why putting `keep_prob` in a collection doesn't work though... it seems like it should be a  viable alternative....

Comment: I thought as well. I've just added the `import_scope="imported"` to the import call, and now I get: `ValueError: Attempted to map inputs that were not found in graph_def: [keep_prob_training:0]`. The placeholder is not a trainable variable as far as I have understood, so maybe I'm not saving it? Can you tell me how to save a placeholder along with all the trainable variables? I'm using the `tf.Saver()`

Comment: Hmm, that sounds like a bug in the current release :(. For the collection approach, you should just be able to call `tf.add_to_collection("KEEP_PROB", keep_prob)` in the original program, and then you'll be able to call `tf.get_collection("KEEP_PROB")[0]` after you import the metagraph.

Comment: Jep exactly what I did :) and I'm able to "get" the `keep_prob` from the collection but setting the `keep_prob: 1.0` in the `feed_dict` has no effect. The predictions is not deterministic. And I've trained a model without dropout to verify that this is in fact the only thing introducing the randomness to the predicitons. Im using TF 0.12.0-rc1 if that makes any difference.

Comment: Could it be non-determinism due to floating point rounding? There are some parallel reductions in TensorFlow, and these will occasionally add up floating-point numbers in a non-deterministic order. (One way to test if the `keep_prob` is having an effect: set `keep_prob: 0.0` at inference time and see if this sets all of the predictions to zero as well.) I don't think the version should matter, but it usually doesn't hurt to upgrade :).

Comment: Just tried setting the `keep_prob: 0.0` with the `get_collection()` approach. Still no luck. The model still predicts all four classes. :) I will ask my University to upgrade. Should I create an issue on git?

Comment: Before you post an issue, can you update the code in the question to show what you have now? It's possible that the `keep_prob` tensor you are getting out of the collection isn't the right one....

Comment: I've just update the code in the question. I save the `keep_prob` by: `tf.add_to_collection('dropout_train', keep_prob)` which is defined as: `keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='keep_prob_training')` in the line just above